# Designation of rows and columns in a 2D dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

The following listing creates a 2D dynamic array.

```
#include <iostream>

#define COLS 3
#define ROWS 3

int ** create2d()
{
    int index = 1;
    int** arr = new int*[COLS];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < COLS ; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[ROWS];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ROWS ; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = index++;
            printf("%d (%d) [%d][%d]\t", arr[i][j], &arr[i][j], i,j);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }
  
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int** arr = create2d();
    for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++) 
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
./main
1 (34979536) [0][0] 2 (34979540) [0][1] 3 (34979544) [0][2]
4 (34980608) [1][0] 5 (34980612) [1][1] 6 (34980616) [1][2]
7 (34980640) [2][0] 8 (34980644) [2][1] 9 (34980648) [2][2]
```

From the output, we see that the increment of the elements and addresses of the elements of the array match.

Are the `COLS` and `ROWS` designations correct?

If so, does that mean that in `arr[p][q]` the left hand index (`p`) can be always considered as column and right hand index (`q`) can always be considered as row?

Comment: You're using the wrong format specifier for `&arr[i][j]`

Comment: No don't use this "C" style approach use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` (see [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)). You will only end up with memory leaks, and unclear ownership of memory this way. Also don't use the preprocessor to define constants in C++, use `static constexpr std::size_t COLS = 3ul;` . Looks like you are learning C++ from an outdated source which still teaches C++ using C

Comment: @PepijnKramer, that was not the concern of this question. :(

Comment: @machine_1 , That was intentional. I just wanted to see decimal values.

Comment: well, you're invoking undefined behavior in the process

Comment: Yes, in this case your matrix is column-major. The first index `p` specifies the column and the second index `q` specifies the row. Consider using better variable names to make that more clear.

Comment: @paddy, In which case matrix is row-major?

Comment: Uhh, if you allocated the outer array with the dimension `ROWS` instead of `COLS`, and _vice versa_ for the inner dimension. This is down to semantics, but those are the names you have used and they are incredibly common. So unless you wanna confuse the heck out of everyone, then `ROWS` should mean "rows" and `COLS` should mean "columns".

Comment: @paddy, But, in that case the increment of elements with not match with the increment of addresses.

Comment: You can represent the elements however you like, and you can represent a logical "address" of an element however you like. Column-major means that elements in a single column are adjacent to eachother in memory. Row-major means the opposite.

Comment: Side notes: 1) It's incorrect to use `%d` format specifier when providing a pointer. Use `%p` instead. 2) It's excessive and wasteful to dynamically allocate every row. For a fixed-size dynamic 2D matrix, in most cases you only need a single 1D vector. 3) You should usually avoid manual memory management and use a container instead. 4) At the very least, provide symmetric functions: _e.g._ implement `destroy2d(int**)`. 5) Encapsulate your matrix in a class to protect against misuse and to allow changes in implementation.

Comment: @user366312 -- [This answer gives you a better approach to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048).

Comment: You do not have a 2D array. You have a 1D array of pointers which are pointing to 1D arrays. Therefore any talk about row-major or column-major order is meaningless. It's your choice which you consider to be the rows and which the columns. If you had an actual 2D array e.g. `int a[3][4];` then the question would be meaningful (though I forget what the answer is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Why do we say that arrays are stored in row-major order in C and C++?

In mathematics, the conventional order for subscripts in a two-dimensional matrix it to put the row subscript first, followed by the column subscript. For a given matrix `A`, the element in row m and column n is denoted `A(m,n)`. It is this convention that will force us to conclude that two-dimensional arrays in C and C++ are stored in row-major order.

Of course, in C and C++, there are no actual two-dimensional arrays. The closest analog is an `array of arrays`. That is what we mean when we say "two-dimensional array."

In the declaration below, `A` is such an array. Its type is `array of arrays of int`.

```cpp
enum : std::size_t { M = 3, N = 2 };
int A[M][N];
```

More precisely, its type is "array of M elements, where each element is an array of N elements of type int." Whew! That's a mouthful.

Here are a few type aliases that spell it out:

```cpp
enum : std::size_t { M = 3, N = 2 };
using array_of_N_ints 
    = int[N];
using array_of_M_arrays_of_N_ints 
    = array_of_N_ints[M];
using M_by_N_matrix 
    = array_of_M_arrays_of_N_ints;
M_by_N_matrix A;
```

The type `M_by_N_matrix` is the same as `int[M][N]`. You can test that, using `std::is_same_v` in a program.

The elements of an `M_by_N_matrix` are referenced using the bracket operator[] twice, e.g. `A[m][n]`. The rules for operator[] mandate a left-to-right binding order, so this is equivalent to `(A[m])[n]`. The meaning is "the nth element of array `A[m]`, where `A[m]` is the mth element of array `A`." Another mouthful!

Now we see why subscript `m` is associated with rows: we want `A[m][n]` in C and C++ to mean the same thing as `A(m,n)` in mathemetics. The first subscript is the row subscript. It's a convention, and nothing more.

Okay, so how do we get to row-major order?

The answer lies is the definition of arrays. The elements of an array are mandated to be stored in contiguous locations (possibly with padding added to satisfy alignment requirements). Element 0 is stored first, followed by element 1, and so on.

In the example above, the elements of array `A` are are arrays. Because M = 3, there are three of them. They are stored consecutively:

A[0]  A[1]  A[2]

But we decided above that the first subscript is a row subscript. A[0] is an array of N ints that corresponds to row 0 in our mathematical matrix. Similarly, A[1] is row 1, and A[2] is row 2. This is row-major order, by definition.

row0 row1 row2

So there you have it: A "two-dimensional array" is stored in row-major order in both C and C++.

By the way, the program below returns 0.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
int main()
{
    enum : std::size_t { M = 3, N = 2 };
    using array_of_N_ints 
        = int[N];
    using array_of_M_arrays_of_N_ints 
        = array_of_N_ints[M];
    using M_by_N_matrix 
        = array_of_M_arrays_of_N_ints;
    M_by_N_matrix A;
    return std::is_same_v<M_by_N_matrix, int[M][N]> ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you output '\n' you are ending a row. The inner loop, therefore, prints the elements of one row. To do that, the column index must range between 0 and what I call n_cols. You hold the row index constant, and vary the column index. Therefore the thing you call ROWS is actually n_cols.

Each iteration of the outer loop prints one row.  How many rows do you print? I would call that n_rows, but you have labeled it COLS.

So I would say, no, your designations of ROWS and COLS are not correct.

If you change COLS to 2, but keep ROWS at 3, your output will contain two rows, not two columns.

You suggest that your j index is a row index, but you print it second, *where it is normal to print the column index.* Basically, you've transposed names just enough to convince yourself that the matrix is stored in column-major order.